# How do I make the diff view wrap text in Sourcetree?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I am using Sourcetree for Mac OS. I am editing markdown files, and my project does not force a column width, instead using carriage returns at the end of a paragraph.

[image]

**How do I make the diff view wrap text in Sourcetree?**